# Failed to upload '.p12' certificate in azure notification hub

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to upload '.p12' certificate to the notification hub but getting fallowing error.[image]

I am using production certificate. In last night I am updating with development certificate, Now I am create new production certificate and creating '.p12' for that certificate. Please suggest any idea of causing of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, this issue may be caused by the validation of your certificate. I would recommend you creating a new Apple Push Notification Client SSL Certificate, for more details you could refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6). Then follow the **Configure the notification hub for APNS** section under [Configure and run the iOS project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#configure-and-run-the-ios-project-optional) to configure the notification hub for APNS to narrow this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the certificate is invalid. Please verify the following.

1. Go into your Keychain
2. Go to Keys
3. Find the right certificate and expand it with the little arrow on the left
4. Select the **certificate only**, this is important. So only the child node should be selected.
5. Right-click it, export, set a password and upload to Mobile Center (or wherever)

Comment: Thanks your support Gerald, In few hours back I have updated development certificate '.p12' file successfully. After some time I have create production certificate '.p12' file and try to uploading I am got this issue. Now I am againg try to upload development certificate '.p12' also show same error.

Comment: I am tried with above procedure, Still getting same problem. Is there any possibility to another reason.